# How to detect if a parameter is a char in a called function which only has int parameters

Tags: c, char, integer

I have a program which write a rectangle with given height and width as parameters and I want to be able to detect if x or y is a char so that I can stop the program and write "Invalid size"

```
void rush(int x, int y)
{
    int curr_line;
    int curr_char;
    
    if (x <= 0 || y <= 0) {
        write(1, "Invalid size\n", 13);
    }
    for (curr_line = 1; curr_line <= y; curr_line ++) {
        if (curr_line == 1 || curr_line == y) {
            draw_line(x, curr_char, 1);
        } else {
            draw_line(x, curr_char, 0);
        }
        write(1, "\n", 1);
    }
}
void main(void)
{
    rush(5, 'g');
}
```

(for example here the 'g' char should make the rush(); write Invalid size)

PS: I am not able to put code in the main(); function.

Comment: With `if(isalpha(x) || isalpha(y))` ...? That will detect the `'g'` you are passing, but it will also refuse rectangle sizes that happen to have the value in that code range passed numerically.

Comment: The arguments to the function call are converted to the parameter types, both `int`. So, when `rush` is called with `'g'`, the value of `'g'` is whatever the C implementation uses for the character “g” (likely 103), and 103 is passed to `rush` with no indication that it was a character constant. In fact, in C, the type of a plain character constant is `int`. The routine `rush` receives 103 in the parameter `y`, which is an `int`, and has no way to tell it originated as a character constant. If 103 is an invalid size, the routine could detect that. But it has to decide based on value, not type.

Comment: `rush( x, y)` invokes `write(1, "Invalid size\n", 13);` when `x` or `y` are 0 as a `char`, `int` or otherwise so knowing the calling argument type is insufficient.

Comment: Alpha chars (e.g. `'g'` which is 0x67 or 103) _are_ valid lengths [for rectangular areas]. So, you can't detect this in the function ... Unless, you want to place a restriction on the mininum value. (e.g.) For VGA resolution, we have 640x480, so you could check that `x >= 640` and `y >= 480`. But, **why** do you care? Most imaging S/W does _not_ care about "passing a char" and only cares about sensible coordinates or dimensions.

Comment: In C, `'g'` is an `int` as is `5`.  Neither is a `char`.

Comment: BobisLeDev, With `draw_line(x, curr_char, 1);`, `curr_char` is never assigned.  What is the goal with this line of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the value of char is 0 to 255 for unsigned and -128 to 127 so when sending a char to a function that recieves an int it will be casted to an int, so unless you want to only have values that are out of the range of char there is no way to do it in C.

Comment: The `'g'` is *already* an `int` and needs no casting.